# flask security separating access data on flask admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin, flask-security

i have an aplication homestay reservation built with flask..
every homestay have an user login, this login built with flask-security and every owner of the homestay have role **User**.
and every user can input their homestay data with flask-admin.
but unfortunately if a user input their data, the others user which have role **User** can seing the data have input too..

so.. my question how to separate the data if a user have the same role..?
user A can just see his data, and user B so too..

this is my **models.py** code:

```
    roles_users = database.Table(
    'roles_users',
    database.Column('user_id', database.Integer(), database.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    database.Column('role_id', database.Integer(), database.ForeignKey('role.id'))
)


class Role(database.Model, RoleMixin):
    id = database.Column(database.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = database.Column(database.String(80), unique=True)
    description = database.Column(database.String(255))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class User(database.Model, UserMixin):
    id = database.Column(database.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = database.Column(database.String(255))
    last_name = database.Column(database.String(255))
    email = database.Column(database.String(255), unique=True)
    password = database.Column(database.String(255))
    active = database.Column(database.Boolean())
    confirmed_at = database.Column(database.DateTime())
    roles = database.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                            backref=database.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Room(database.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'room'
    room_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    room_name = Column(String)
    room_description = Column(String)
    room_images = Column(database.Unicode(128))
    room_price = Column(Integer) 
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id))
```

and this is my **views.py** :

```
class UserAccess(ModelView):

    def is_accessible(self):
        if not current_user.is_active or not current_user.is_authenticated:
            return False
        if current_user.has_role('user'):
            return True

        return False

    def _handle_view(self, name, **kwargs):
        """
        Override builtin _handle_view in order to redirect users when a view is not accessible.
        """
        if not self.is_accessible():
            if current_user.is_authenticated:
                # permission denied
                abort(403)
            else:
                # login
                return redirect(url_for('security.login', next=request.url))

class Room(UserAccess):
    form_overrides = dict(keterangan_kamar=CKEditorField)
    create_template = 'admin/ckeditor.html'
    edit_template = 'admin/ckeditor.html'
    column_list = ('room_name', 'room_images', 'room_price')
    def _list_thumbnail(view, context, model, name):
        if not model.room_images:
            return ''

        return Markup('<img src="%s">' % url_for('static',
                                                 filename=form.thumbgen_filename(model.room_images)))

    column_formatters = {
        'room_images': _list_thumbnail
    }

    # Alternative way to contribute field is to override it completely.
    # In this case, Flask-Admin won't attempt to merge various parameters for the field.
    form_extra_fields = {
        'room_images': form.ImageUploadField('Room Images',
                                      base_path=file_path,
                                      thumbnail_size=(100, 100, True))
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a permanent filter to your `Room` view by overriding [`get_query`](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_contrib_sqla/?highlight=get_count_query#flask_admin.contrib.sqla.ModelView.get_query) and [`get_count_query`](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_contrib_sqla/?highlight=get_count_query#flask_admin.contrib.sqla.ModelView.get_count_query)

For example (note I've named your `Room` class to `RoomView` as you already have a class called `Room` representing the database model):

```
class RoomView(UserAccess):

    def get_query(self):
        return self.session.query(self.model).filter(
            Room.user_id == current_user.id
        )

    def get_count_query(self):
        return self.session.query(func.count('*')).select_from(self.model).filter(
            Room.user_id == current_user.id
        )

    #  ... your code etc
```

Comment: Thank you for your respon @pjcunningham , i have followed your instruction, but i got the the new error when i added to my **views.py** :
'sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) table name "room" specified more than once'