# How to separate views model by id with Flask-admin?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login, flask-admin

I make a tuition payment app with **Flask** and using **Flask-admin** as database management for every school who have registered with my app.

I already make it, but now I'm really not sure how to separate data access between every school account who have registered to manage their own tuition payment.

With **Flask-login**, I can do it with this code:

```
@app.route('/school_admin')
@login_required
def school_admin():
    school_data = db.session.query(Student.id, Student.name).filter_by(school_id=current_user.id).all()
    return render_template('school_admin_dashboard.html', school_data=school_data)
```

But, because **Flask-admin** generates it table views automatically, I'm really not sure how to do that..?

So far, I have made my **ModelView** like this:

```
class SchoolAdminModelView(sqla.ModelView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        if not current_user.is_active or not current_user.is_authenticated:
            return False
        if current_user.has_role('schooladmin'):
            return True

        return False

    def _handle_view(self, name, **kwargs):
        if not self.is_accessible():
            if current_user.is_authenticated:
                # permission denied
                abort(403)
            else:
                # login
                return redirect(url_for('security.login', next=request.url))

class StudentModelView(SchoolAdminModelView):
    pass

admin.add_view(StudentModelView(Student, db.session))
```

So, how to separate view model by **school_id**..?

**NOTE:** my reason why am I using **Flask-admin** instead of **Flask-login** for school Admin because of it pretty simple to manage **user** and **superuser** roles.
And I have using **Flask-login** for Parent of the student who is the user who consumes this App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code almost works @Joost, but I added a little bit method to it.

I've found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521364/flask-security-separating-access-data-on-flask-admin) and modify it a little bit, this is the code how to separate the data access between different school using this way:

```
class StudentModelView(sqla.ModelView):
    def get_query(self):
        return Student.query.filter_by(school_id=current_user.id)

    def get_count_query(self):
        return self.session.query(func.count('*')).select_from(self.model).filter(
            Student.school_id == current_user.id
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the logged in user has a `school_id` connected to them:

```
class SchoolAdminModelView(sqla.ModelView):
    def get_query(self):
        return super(SchoolAdminModelView, self).get_query().filter(School.id == current_user.school_id)
```

It filters the query which is used to generate the list of items in the table. You might have to adjust it a bit to your exact needs.

Comment: Is the current user logger in? Does `current_user` display something in normal `app.routes`?